# osx fn and select key not responding on external keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, external, keymapping

I have a MacBook Pro (from 2015) and an external keyboard ([DuckyZero 2108](http://www.duckychannel.com.tw/en/ZERO_DK2108.html)).

I have already swapped the modifier keys 'option/alt' and 'command' on the left side of my external keyboard to make it behave like my internal keyboard.

I have tried to map the 'fn' key, which is on the right side of my external keyboard, to 'option/alt' with KeyRemapFor4MacBook ([karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)) with no succes. Againt, to make sure that my external keyboard behaves like my internal keyboard.

It seems that the keys 'fn' and 'select' on my externel keyboard are not detected when pressed by my MacBook (checked this with Keyboard Viewer), thus mapping with KeyRemapFor4MacBook has no effect.

The 'fn' key works on hardware level and the 'select' key is detected by http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html (could not test the 'fn' key on keyboard.com due to the absence of the 'fn' key in their layout).

My question is, is it possible to make the 'fn' and/or 'select' key on my external keyboard respond/detect after being pressed, so that I can remap it to 'option/alt'?